# How to force a legend inside a plot to be horizontal and not vertical?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'd like the legend inside the plot to be horizontal (each one is beside each other not one is above the other)

Is there a way to change from vertical to horizontal?
Example:

```
    mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl, labels=c("four","six","eight"))
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, colour=cyl)) + geom_point(aes(colour=cyl)) + 
   opts(legend.position = c(0, 1), title="Legend placement makes me sad")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get horizontal legend by adding argument `legend.direction="horizontal"` inside the `theme()` or `opts()`

```
theme(legend.direction="horizontal")
```

Older versions

```
opts(legend.direction="horizontal")
```

Answer (score 5):

When you create your legend, you can use the argument 'horiz' which is automatically at FALSE

```
legend( ... , horiz=TRUE)
```